# Wrapper a cada 3 itens em uma listagem

Tags: javascript, react, api

Tenho uma api que me retorna uma listagem de clientes e tenho o seguinte layout, minha dúvida é como colocar a div de bg cinza claro a cada 3 itens.
Segue o meu código.

```
<Grid container justify="flex-start" spacing={2}>
  {data.map((profile) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <CardProfile profile={profile} />
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: onde você pegou esse `Grid` ou seja, esses componentes?

Comment: é do material-ui https://material-ui.com/pt/components/grid/